# jQuery fadeIn is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, fadein

I have the following HTML DIV which does not work using FadeIn in IE:

```
$(".tip").fadeIn("slow"); /* Is not working in IE. */
$(".tip").show(); /* Works well in IE, that's weird. */



<div class="tip"  style="width: 220px; display: none;">
            <div class="tip-header">
                <span><b>Title</b></span>
                <div class="right close"><a href="javascript:void(0);">close</a> <img alt=""  src="/Images/close-normal.png"/></div>
            </div>

            <div class="tip-content">EBody comes here.</div>
        </div> 


.tip
{
    display: block; 
    z-index: 99999; 
    position: fixed; 
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
    border:solid 1px #82C2FA;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
}

.tip-header
{
    padding: 8px; 
    min-height: 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px; 
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius-topleft: 8px; 
     background-color: #CFE6FD; 
     border-bottom: 1px solid #82C2FA;  
}

.tip-header span
{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666666;
}

.tip-content
{
    padding: 8px; 
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.close, .whats-this
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.close a
{
    color: #085FBC; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.close img
{
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: What version(s) of IE? Do you have a link to the page?

Comment: I can confirm that the `fadeIn()` method does work in IE on the jQuery documentation page. My suspicion is an issue in your CSS.

Comment: I am using IE 8. Check this page http://jsfiddle.net/Cxvdk/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `$(".tip").show();` line, it is implicit in the `FadeIn()` method.

Here's a working example (IE8)

http://jsfiddle.net/Cxvdk/1/

Comment: Ben,
I know that $(".tip").show(); is implicit and un-necessary, but I want to tell you from this that .show works while .fadeIn does not. I updated your jsFiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/Cxvdk/4/. Please check it. I added an outer DIV which caused the issue.

??

Comment: @Nazaf - Your example is working on IE8, at least for me. What version of IE do you have?

Comment: I have IE 8. Here is a detailed screenshot. Check here http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/3838/ie8g.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Ben, 
I know that `$(".tip").show();` is implicit and un-necessary,  but I want to tell you from this that **.show** works while **.fadeIn** does not. I updated your jsFiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/Cxvdk/4/. Please check it. I added an outer DIV which caused the issue.

??

Answer (score 0):

Delete this from the css and it will work:

.section
{
    display: block;
}

Comment: Sorry. I mean, delete ".section
{
    display: inline-block;
}" or add ".section
{
    display: block;
}".